Navbar gone wrong: handling "is not a function error" in layout.tsx
I'm a React (Next.js) beginner and I'm trying to implement a navbar feature. I have a function that updates the navlinks' state and make a navlink stand out if the user is on the page that link refers to. This is working ok, but, in such a approach, I need to retrieve the path the user is accessing to properly update my UI.
My idea is to use layout.tsx to call a custom hook which updates my navbar.
This hook will update my data:
// src/utils/useInitNavigation.ts
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { updateNavigationCurrentStatus } from "../data/navigationData";

export default function useInitNavigation() {
  useEffect(() => {
    updateNavigationCurrentStatus(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);
}

This is my troublesome layout.tsx code:
// src/app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navbar from "@/components/ui/navigation/Navbar";
import useInitNavigation from "@/utils/useInitNavigation"; // Ensure this path is correct

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My App",
  description: "This is a Navbar test",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  useInitNavigation();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


I'm getting the following error message:

Error: (0 , utils_useInitNavigation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_.default) is not a function

I'm trying this implementation (instead of directly injecting useInitNavigation.ts code into layout.tsx) because I get a compilation error when I try to use "use client" and metadata at the same time.
I'm looking for a solution to the current issue or a better approach to the feature I'm trying to implement.

if you console.log your useInitNavigation in RootLayout before calling it, what is it?

Nothing appears. Actually, nothing happens even if I try to log a string. But that gave me an idea. Maybe it will run if I use it as a component.

Trying to log things didn't work, so my guess is that no functions outside return will work properly. I changed my approach to avoid the issue described.
First of all, I created a new tsx component and called it NavbarHook. This component won't return html but it will execute useInitNavigation.
Then, I used  before  in my layout.tsx in order to execute the code snippet in every single page.
I'm still now sure whether this is the best approach or not, but it worked!
